# Unable to copy or select text on a website

Tags: html, css

A school website doesn't let me copy text or select it.

Other websites work fine, but that website doesn't work.

*Is there a way to bypass that and copy the text?*

[image]

> The website is https://www.chimica-online.it/download/sistema-internazionale-unita-misura.htm

**What I really want**

Something like this:

[image]

---

**What I tried**

I tried to use this CSS:

```
* {
  user-select: auto !important;
}
```

> When creating navbars I sometimes use this CSS property for not allowing text selection: `user-select: none;`
>
> But in their case I think they are using it on the entire website. This is why I tried to use `*` CSS selector, but is not working.

Comment: They may have some clever JavaScript which gets in the way of this functionality by directly modifying text selection or redirecting click or drag events.  Getting around it may take more work.  Press F12 to see your browser's debugging tools.  You can disable JavaScript, directly access the page source or current DOM, etc.  Essentially this is a game of walls and ladders regarding how much effort they put in to protect the data and how much effort you put in to copy it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just open devtools, and write `document.onselectstart = ""`

### [image]

**how I find it?**

I opened dev tools, and I tried your code, and actually is not work,

so I think that they didn't use the CSS trick,

so I tried to see if they have some scripts.

the script that seems interesting is this one:

[image]

now what what is there:
[image]

they write cleverly this code `onstartselect = return false` (so it not your browser bug, but they want to do it)

that it, I used devtools and I overridde it. setting it to `""` empty string

the solution is write `document.onselectstart = ""`

Answer (score 3):

The problem doesn't reside in CSS. Opening the dev tools, and navigating to the JS in the sources section, shows that there is this function:

`document.onselectstart = new Function("return false");`

This basically makes the text unselectable, no matter what CSS attributes you fiddle with. You'll need to overwrite this JS functionality.

The culprit exists on line 25 of a prettier formatted version of the general_4.js file.

You can overwrite it by pasting this into the dev tools console:

`document.onselectstart = new Function("return true");`

Or use a custom injection of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the page, select print, select as PDF, then select the text from here. Ive tried it and it works

In order to make a set of quantities with their units of measurement
universal, i.e. to ensure that the whole world uses the same reference
system, the International System of Measurement (IS) came into force in
1978. It replaced both the CGS system and the MKS system.
The International System provides for precise rules regarding the way of
writing the units of measurement and their respective symbols.
For example,:
Units of measurement, even if they derive from proper names, should
always be written in lowercase and without an accent;
Unit symbols should be written in lowercase. Exceptions are the symbols
of the units of measurement that derive from a proper name: in these cases
the initial must be capitalized;
Unit symbols must be written after the numeric value and

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).